# How do I set an environment variable for airflow to use?

Tags: python, environment-variables, airflow

Airflow is returning an error when trying to run a DAG saying that it can't find an environment variable, which is odd because it's able to find 3 other environment variables that I'm storing as a Python variable. No issues with those variables at all.

I have all 4 variables in `~/.profile` and have also done

```
export var1="varirable1"
export var2="varirable2"
export var3="varirable3"
export var4="varirable4"
```

Under what user does `airflow` run? I've done those `export` commands under `sudo` as well, so I thought they would be picked up by `airflow` when it runs the dag

Comment: Are you able to access that fourth variable through the normal shell within that server on which airflow is running?

Comment: If you add variables in the `~/.profile` file, you may need to restart your PC. Otherwise, better to set variables in  `~/.bashrc` as mentioned by @Breathe.

Answer (score 3):

Is it maybe because airflow uses non-login shell? Have you tried putting these lines in : ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.profile ?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226955/4976878), the variables should be put in `/etc/default/airflow` (on Debian/Ubuntu) or `/etc/sysconfig/airflow` (on Centos/Redhat).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just running a local instance you should be able to use environment variables like you expect. Remember that you need to set them in the shell that is running the webserver and scheduler though. If these are in your `.profile`, you may need to run `source ~/.profile`.