# spark-submit command not found in airflow

Tags: bash, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I am trying to run my spark job in airflow, when I executed this command  `spark-submit --class dataload.dataload_daily /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/scripts/data_to_s3-assembly-0.1.jar` in terminal, it works fine without any issue.

However, I am doing the same here in airflow, but keep getting the error

> /tmp/airflowtmpKQMdzp/spark-submit-scalaWVer4Z: line 1: spark-submit:
>   command not found

```
t1 = BashOperator(task_id = 'spark-submit-scala',
bash_command = 'spark-submit --class dataload.dataload_daily \
/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/scripts/data_to_s3-assembly-0.1.jar',
dag=dag,
retries=0,
start_date=datetime(2018, 4, 14))
```

I have my spark path mentioned in bash_profile,

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
```

sourced this file as well. Not sure how to debug this, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with `bash_command = 'echo $PATH'` to see if your path is being updated correctly.

This is because you are metioning editing the *bash_profile*, but as far as I know Airflow is being run as another user. Since the other user has no changes in the bash_profile, the path to Spark might be missing.

As mentioned here ([How do I set an environment variable for airflow to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980616/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-airflow-to-use)) you could try setting the path in `.bashrc`.